# focus-within on a div or some other element with css only

Tags: css, focus

I need an element to change when any of its child elements are focused so I tried focus-within. However, this doesn't seem to work for elements other than text inputs. Is there any alternative out there with CSS only?

```css
form{ border:1px solid black;}
form:focus-within {
  background-color:red;
  
}
div {background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text">
 <div>
  click here
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's because a div is not focus-able, by just clicking a div you aren't focusing on it. Have you thought about making your div a button instead?

Comment: Could you describe more what you want to happen? In what way do you want the div element to influence the focus-within status of the form element? Or do you just want the color of the div element to change when anything in the form is focused?

Comment: I k now but I cant change the html. I want the same red effect to happen when you click on the div as when you click on the text input.

Comment: I don't believe that CSS can influence whether an element is focusable or not. It needs some HTML such as setting a tabindex attribute.